# Session losing its state after javascript function call

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, session-state

We are using Sharepoint 2007
We initialising the session variable on page load
We have one javascript function as mentioned below

```
function backclick()
{
 __doPostBack('btnCaseSearch', 'Click'); 
alert('Select the Search Criteria.');
}
```

but after calling this we are losing session value.
If we remove __doPostBack('btnCaseSearch', 'Click'); 
then alert is displaying each time when page gets load but session is not losing its value.
How to maintain session pls help or suggest some alternative to _doPostBack()

the sceneario is like this
below javascript function

```
function backclick()
{
 __doPostBack('btnCaseSearch', 'Click'); 
alert(result not found.');
}

function check()
{
var btn ="<%=Session["search"]%>";
if(btn == "true")
{
do something
}
else
{
else part
}
```

Below server side code

```
Page_Load()
{
//initialise session variable
session["search"] = "true";
}
btnSearch_click()
{
 if(result not found)
{
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"page_index_script1", "backclick();", true);

}
}
```

so when backclick() javascript function gets called at that time session is losing its state but if backclick() doesn't get called then code works perferctly

Thanks

Comment: the sceneario is like this
below javascript function
function backclick()
{
 __doPostBack('btnCaseSearch', 'Click'); 
alert('Select the Search Criteria.');
}

function check()
{
if(session == "true")
{
do something
}
else
{
else part
}

Below server side code
Page_Load()
{
//initialise session variable
session["search"] = "true";
}

so when backclick() javascript function gets called at that time session is losing its state but if backclick() doesn't get called then code works perferctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something which jumped out at me:

> We initialising the session variable on page load

Is this page load **server-side**?

Each time you `_doPostBack` will cause pageLoad to execute, so I believe this is where you're overwriting your session variable.

The *only way* the session will loose it's state is:

- If it gets overwritten or removed (use a breakpoint to check you're not setting it twice!)
- The browser is not surrendering the cookie on subsequent requests

Check both of these and if your problem isn't solved post what you found.

Comment: yes Page load is on server side.
We are assigning value to session variable on page load say "true"
and in In javascript we are checking session value,but we are getting session value as "null" instead of "true"

Comment: @Rushikesh - Exactly how are you checking this value in javascript (since a session variable wouldn't normally end up on the client)

Comment: below is the code by which we are checking session value in javascript
var btn ="<%=Session["sessionName"]%>";
if(btn == "clicked")
{
}

Comment: @Rushikesh In that case I believe you're resetting in page load

Comment: yes we are setting it on page_load but in javascript it shows null

Comment: Can you please just modify your question to show the **whole** of the javascript and the **whole** of the pageLoad? For example `<%=Session["sessionName"]%>` isn't in your question anywhere

Comment: you can check now..I have modified the question
Thanks a lot for trying to solve this problem :)

Comment: @Rushikesh - I'm not sure I can follow your code properly (for example what is `part`?)  I've updated my answer to show what's likely to be happening here - you need to investigate and tell us what you found.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help..
We didn't understand what was the issue.
finaly what we did is..we initialised that session in master page load and it is workin fine now

Comment: @Rushikesh - Ok glad you got it, I was concentrating on the content page but as you found it can also happen in the master page. Mark as answer?

Comment: Thanks for giving time and continious support...
:)